# MySQL 8 significant performance drop from local to container

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose

I have a local MySQL 8.0.18 for Win64 on Windows 10/IIS running on PHP 7 FastCGI module.

Production is to be in containers, with **mysql:latest** and **php:fpm-buster**. This is my first experience with deploying to containers, so it is absolutely possible I'm missing something.

For MySQL, I mounted the local's Data directory, which seems to have maintained all the indexes, including the spatial index on stopPoint.

It's working, but I'm seeing an enormous performance drop on the container for a query with ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE in the WHERE. I did move from php:apache to php:fpm-buster to see if there was any difference, but none.

The WHERE seems to be what's causing the pain, but I'm just not sure why there is such a significant difference between the two versions.

Query execution side-by-side (container on left):
[image: Query exec time comparison]

The query is:

```
SET @pt = ST_POINTFROMTEXT(CONCAT('Point(', ?, ' ', ?, ')'), 4326);
SELECT ST_LATITUDE(stopPoint) AS lat, ST_LONGITUDE(stopPoint) AS lng, ROUND(ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(stopPoint, @pt), 1) AS distance
                    FROM `stops`
                    WHERE ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(stopPoint, @pt) <= ?
                    ORDER BY ABS(ST_LATITUDE(stopPoint) - ?) + ABS(ST_LONGITUDE(stopPoint) - ?) DESC
```